# Link in drop down select not working IE8/9 to open drop down select link, alert works

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, window.open

It appears IE8 and 9 are giving me grief and I can't think of an alternative.

**The following works in Chrome, FF and Safari.**

There are two drop downs, each containing two links. Each drop down has it's own corresponding "Buy Now" button. When a drop down selection is made, the url is loaded via jquery and when user clicks "Buy Now" button, a new window opens to the corresponding drop down selection.

In IE8/9 when a user selects a drop down and clicks the buy now button, it throws the alert that selection wasn't made.

[See JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/coltanious/AJDEB/15/)

Jquery:

```
    $(".buyNow").on("click", function (e) {
     var url = $(e.target).parent().children().find("[data-active]").data("val");
    if (url) {
        window.open(url, "_blank");
    } else {
        window.alert("Please select a bag size.");
    }
})
```

Comment: What kind of grief? What happens? Do you get any error message?

Comment: works fine for me in IE

Comment: @epascarello Hmm, I can't seem to get it to work in ie8 or 9. The actually website is www.dangfoods.com/shop.php

Comment: @Guffa, it doesn't recognize the URL and throws the alert as if there is no selection made in the dropdown.

Comment: There is a JS Error on the page `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'stopPropagation' of undefined or null reference 
presspage.js, line 20 character 3` Fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the fact the e.target is different than the other browsers. So parent is a different element and it can not find the attriute since it is not a child. Simple debugging will show it.

Use `.closest(".someClass")` to get the element you are after instead of `.parent()`.

or change

```
var url = $(e.target)...
```

to

```
var url = $(this)...
```